# Android xml animation loading

Tags: android, xml, rotation, imageview, animationdrawable

This is the effect I would like to have:

[image]

I have the following image, how can I make xml animate like what you see in the picture?

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

imgAnimate:

```xml
<vector android:height="16dp" android:tint="#F5AF45"
    android:viewportHeight="16" android:viewportWidth="16"
    android:width="16dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="m8,1.5a6.5,6.5 0 1 0 0,13a6.5,6.5 0 0 0 0,-13zm-8,6.5a8,8 0 1 1 16,0a8,8 0 0 1 -16,0z" android:fillAlpha="0.2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="m7.25,0.75a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 0.75,-0.75a8,8 0 0 1 8,8a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 -1.5,0a6.5,6.5 0 0 0 -6.5,-6.5a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 -0.75,-0.75z"  />
</vector>
```